# How to extract and count text or numeric characters from a sequence in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to extract and count the amount of all the characters that are red in each cell according to the criteria search done above in the table, does anyone have a solution? The characters I get I wanted to extract and count the amount,?[image]

Comment: Would the first extraction be `DC KP5` or `DC KP5 DC` and would the count be `2`,`3`, or `7`?

Comment: DC KP5 DC, I want to extract repeated characters if they are in the search

Comment: And the count by character, word,...?

Comment: DC = 1, KP5 = 1, DC =1. Total: 3

Comment: what version of excel are you using?

Comment: 2019 version....

Comment: I also wish I had an option if I didn't want to repeat same characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Extraction this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A12," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A12," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),$B$9:$D$9&"",0)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A12," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A12," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This iterates each "word" and then tries to find it in the range, if found it is returned to the TEXTJOIN.

Then for the count:

```
=LEN(B12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B12," ",""))+1
```

[image]

Comment: It worked only with the search for "KP5" and "2000", the other values ​​she did not seek, she translated into Portuguese

Comment: Did you use `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to force it into an array formula?

Comment: =UNIRTEXTO(" ";VERDADEIRO;SE(ÉNÚM(CORRESP(ARRUMAR(EXT.TEXTO(SUBSTITUIR(A13;" ";REPT(" ";999));(LIN($ZZ$1:ÍNDICE($ZZ:$ZZ;NÚM.CARACT(A13)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A13;" ";""))+1))-1)*999+1;999));$B$9:$D$9&"";0));ARRUMAR(EXT.TEXTO(SUBSTITUIR(A13;" ";REPT(" ";999));(LIN($ZZ$1:ÍNDICE($ZZ:$ZZ;NÚM.CARACT(A13)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A13;" ";""))+1))-1)*999+1;999));""))

Comment: Check her out, I just translated her into Portuguese and I applied it in a matrix way and yet she only extracted the "KP5"

Comment: Then look at the value in B9 and make sure there are no spaces or other non printable characters before or after the `DC`

Comment: Yes, there was a space after "DC", now it worked!

Comment: If I want not to repeat the characters, for example the "DC" as I do ???

Comment: That is a new question and will require a totally new formula.

Comment: My God ... kkkk

Comment: I've seen extensive formulas, but yours is huge! Would it be possible to send to me in private, the formula changed not to repeat the values?

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX($9:$9,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$B$9:$D$9&" "," "&A12&" ")),COLUMN(B9:D9)*{1;1}))))))`

Comment: Amazing! It worked! Thanks

Comment: I have just started studying advanced matrix formulas, I want to reach her level, I will study it here and see how it works. I thought I already knew a lot, but I don't know ... kkkk

Comment: Hi! Sorry to bother you, but can you tell me the source of that first "TextJoin ()" formula that you posted for me ?? Can you tell me why it only accepts a maximum of 80 characters per cell ?? I tried with more than 100 characters and she gives the error and does not bring the separate matrix range, can you tell me why ??